# TypeScript module and class simultaneously?

Tags: class, module, typescript

I am currently trying to build a TypeScript definition file for OpenLayers.

The problem is that in OpenLayers there are certain classes that would translate to both a module and a class in TypeScript.

For example there is the `Protocol` class in module `OpenLayers` and there is a class `Response` in module `OpenLayers.Protocol`.

How could I model that in TypeScript? Can I make `Protocol` a class and define the `Response` class as a inner class that is exported? How would you go about solving that problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to declare a nest class structure in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495107/any-way-to-declare-a-nest-class-structure-in-typescript)

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Response` as a `static` field of `Protocol` with a constructor type, returning an `interface` that defines the `Response` class:

```
declare module OpenLayers {
    export interface IProtocolResponse {
        foo(): void;
    }

    export class Protocol {
        static Response: new () => IProtocolResponse;
    }
}

var response = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Response();
response.foo();
```

**Edit:**

Or as Anders points out in [this discussion list question](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/399101), you can have multiple constructors for the inner class in this way:

```
declare module OpenLayers {
    export interface IProtocolResponse {
        foo(): void;
    }

    export class Protocol {
        static Response: {
            new (): IProtocolResponse;
            new (string): IProtocolResponse;
        };
    }
}

var response = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Response('bar');
response.foo();
```

The main downside of both approaches is that you cannot derive a class from `OpenLayers.Protocol.Response`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my updated answer, which I hope helps - it should get you started on defining OpenType:

```
declare module OpenType {
   export class Protocol {
       constructor();
       Request;
   }
}

var x = new OpenType.Protocol();
var y = new  x.Request();
var z = x.Request;
```

Comment: Both solutions are not possible sadly. The first one because it isn't really what I want since Protocol.Response should hold the class not an instance of it. The second one is sadly also not possible since I can't just rename classes in OpenLayers :(.

Comment: I've added a third attempt to see if that's what you are after.

Comment: Ok the thing is that I am building TypeScript (typed JavaScript from Microsoft) definition files. They are not really an implementation but rather a kind of interface declaration. Therefore sadly also the third solution doesn't work.

Comment: Ah - okay - so you just want to be able to define an existing JavaScript file.

Comment: In fact - you stated that in your question, so I apologise for missing that!

Comment: Mhhh that would work somewhat but the thing is that with this solution I can't define the interface of the Request class, can I?

Comment: You could define it and then use a cast... `var y = <IRequest> new x.Request();`

Comment: Well the whole point of TypeScript definition files is to enable me to use OpenLayers as normal just with the added "type safety" at development time.

I can't change the way OpenLayers builds and instantiates its classes.