# Any way to declare a nest class structure in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm interested in defining an existing framework (openlayers.d.ts) but cannot figure out how to express the fact that OpenLayers.Layer is both a class and a namespace for OpenLayers.Layer.Markers.  I believe this makes Markers a nested class of Layer.

usage:

```
l = new OpenLayers.Layer(...); // this is a base class, never do this
m = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers(...);
```

How would you declare both the Layer and Markers class in typescript?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the unanswered question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12799433/typescript-module-and-class-simultaneously

Comment: Not talking about how you would want to model this from a *declaration*  perspective but TypeScript does now have nested class support : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32494175/390330

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This seems like it has been fixed in versions 0.9.1.1 and later. You just have to create a module with the same name as the class where you want to nest types, and put your nested types in it.

More concretely, this is how you do it:

```
declare module a
{
    class b
    {
    }

    module b
    {
        class c
        {
        }
    }
}

var myB = new a.b();
var myC = new a.b.c();
```

This works as well when nesting types in typescript code with the export keyword:

```
export module a
{
    export class b
    {
    }

    export module b
    {
        export enum c
        {
            C1 = 1,
            C2 = 2,
            C3 = 3,
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned by the user @recursive in the comments below, the order of declaration is important. So the class definition must be located before the module with the nested types.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but then I realized that the order is important.  This only seems to work if you declare the class first, and then the module.  It does not work the other way around.

Comment: How do you do this with an Angular project using Typescript? Modules use the decorator: @NgModule

Comment: Anyway to achieve this without pyramid of declarations?

Comment: @jayarjo not that I am aware of. Pyramids of declarations would be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 15):

You can use namespace/class merging to get an equivalent effect to nested classes. This example is adapted from Chapter 1 of Pro TypeScript.

You perform merging with a class and a namespace, or with a function and a namespace.

> In all cases, the namespace must appear after the class or function for the merge to work.

Adapted example:

```
class Outer {

}

namespace Outer {
    export class Mid {

    }

    export module Mid {
        export class Inner {

        }
    }
}

var a = new Outer();
var b = new Outer.Mid();
var x = new Outer.Mid.Inner();
```

Comment: how to call method from Mid class to Outer class?

Comment: Should the whole thing reside in single file? Or can we have implementations separate from declarations?

Comment: @jayarjo all namespaces in the same common root contribute to a single name. So you can have several files all adding to the same namespace if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

As of 2016, I guess this is easier:

```
class A {
    static B = class { }
}

var a = new A();
var b = new A.B();
```

Comment: I get this compile error `Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts` with atom latest ts plugin

Comment: How can you refer to the `this` of `A` within a method of `B` without passing it as an argument explicitly? Or is that impossible since `B` is static? My current solution is to just have a `bFactory` method on `A` where I can access `A` members and pass them to the `B` constructor explicitly, but I was hoping there was a slicker way to do it.

Comment: @Monkpit: `this` refers to an `a` object, and not to the `A` class. You can instantiate many `a`s, and many `b`s, each with its own `this`. So how could a particular `b` know which `a` you would like it to access?

Comment: @MarcG As class `A` is not static, any instance of an `a` object contains the definition of a static class `B`, no? Otherwise, why would `B` be defined in the scope of `A` at all? I'm probably totally missing the point here...

Comment: @Monkpit: any `a` instance contains the DEFINITION of the `B` class, and as such can instantiate `b`s. But you may instantiate `b`s without instantiating `a`s, as you can see in my example `var b = new A.B();`.

Comment: vscode with latest everything also gives `Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts` with this, pointing at the word `class` as the problem.

Comment: Ah, apparently this syntax isn't valid in a d.ts file.  :/  I was really hoping to get better syntax for writing definition files for node modules that export a class that has nested classes dangling off of it.  I guess this isn't the solution for that.

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is no support for nested classes.

http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/460

Comment: This has been fixed in versions 0.9.1.1 and later. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bit late but others may find it useful. This is how I did it to fool TS to accomplish the task.

```
declare module OpenLayers {
  interface Layer { 
   ....
  }

  interface Markers {
    ....
  }

  var Layer: {
    new(name:string, options?:any):Layer;
    prototype:Layer;
    Markers: { 
      new(params?:any):Markers;
      prototype: Markers;
    }
  }
}

var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers();
```

Comment: How can you have a variable named Layer in the same scope as an interface named Layer?

Answer (score 3):

Use TypeScript's *class expressions* for this:

```
var OpenLayers = class {
    static Layer = class {
        static Markers = class {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it also works if the top level object is `export`ed? I am facing following error: `Public static property 'myprop' of exported class has or using private name '(Anonymous class)'`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @SayanPal don't know what you are trying to do