# Typescript definitions: how to declare class inside class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two javascript classes, one called AmazingMultiplier and one called AmazingAdder. I am struggling with writing typescript definition of AmazingAdder.
The javascript file, looks like the following:

```
MyModule.AmazingAdder = function(options){
     //some amazing code

 };

MyModule.AmazingAdder.Statuses={
   success: 1,
   failure: 2
};
```

I am not sure how to declare the statuses object in my typescript definitions file. My `d.ts` file looks like:

```
declare module MyModule
{
  export class AmazingMultiplier
  {
       result: number;
       constructor(params: any?)
  }

 export class AmazingAdder
  {
     constructor(params: any?)
     class Statuses
     {
        success: number,
        failure: number
     }
  }

}
```

However I get unexpected token for 'class' where Statuses are defined. Any assistance would be appreciated. I have read through the tutorials but don't understand how I would do this.

Comment: I don't think you can create nested classes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any way to nest classes in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495107/any-way-to-nest-classes-in-typescript)

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @George Nemes. It is a contrived example. All I want to do is learn how to declare a class within another class in typescript. The duplicate link has helped though and seems to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class and module with the same name. Also, you'll want to use an enum for `Statuses`:

```
declare module MyModule {
    class AmazingAdder {
        constructor(params?: any);
    }
    module AmazingAdder {
        enum Statuses {
            success = 1,
            failure = 2,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are other potential solutions. But this is the most idiomatic one that I would do myself