# Is it possible to define a type (string literal union) within a class in TypeScript?

Tags: types, typescript, typescript1.8

In TypeScript 1.8, they added a new type called a "string literal type" which lets you declare a type that can only be one of a set of finite values. The example that they give is:

```
type Easing = "ease-in" | "ease-out" | "ease-in-out";
```

But, in all their examples, the type is either defined *outside* of the class that it is used in or defined inline without an alias. As explained (fairly tersely) in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436192/what-is-the-scope-of-a-type-alias), type alias declarations are scoped to their containing module.

In my project, I would like to define type aliases for string literals that are paired with specific classes and used in multiple places. Because of the structure of the APIs that I am consuming, there are multiple classes which each have properties of the same name but different potential values. I'd like to keep my code neat and not have a bunch of global type declarations with prefixes (`MyClassAPropertyValue`, `MyClassBPropertyValue`, etc.) if I can help it.

**So, is there any way to declare a `type` within class scope (preferably so that it is consumable from external modules)?** If not, is there a close substitute or planned feature that will fill this use case?

---

Use case:

Suppose I have two classes that wrap my underlying API data. Each class represents different data, they just happen to have some properties with the same name. I want a way of defining properties like so:

```
export class APIObjectA {
    // Valid values in APIObjectA
    public type Property1Value = "possible_value_A" | "possible_value_B";
    public type Property2Value = "possible_value_C" | "possible_value_D";

    // Here, "Property1Value" refers to the version in APIObjectA
    public get property1(): Property1Value {
        // Return value of property1 from underlying API data
    }

    public get property2(): Property2Value {
        // ...
    }
}

export class APIObjectB {
    // Valid values in APIObjectB
    public type Property1Value = "possible_value_E" | "possible_value_F";
    public type Property2Value = "possible_value_G" | "possible_value_H";

    // In this context, "Property1Value" refers to the version in APIObjectB
    public get property1(): Property1Value {
        // ...
    }

    public get property2(): Property2Value {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then, ideally, I'd be able to refer to a specific type in consuming code so that I have types everywhere:

```
var myNewValue: APIObjectB.Property1Value = "possible_value_F";
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking, but can you add some code as an example of how you intend to use this type?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't define types (whether they be nested classes, enums or string literal types) directly inside a class.

But, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33301725/4397397), you can get around this by defining the nested type in a module of the same name.

```
export class APIObjectA {
    // Here, "Property1Value" refers to the version in APIObjectA
    public get property1(): APIObjectA.Property1Value {
        // Return value of property1 from underlying API data
    }

    public get property2(): APIObjectA.Property2Value {
        // ...
    }
}

module APIObjectA {
    // Valid values in APIObjectA
    export type Property1Value = "possible_value_A" | "possible_value_B";
    export type Property2Value = "possible_value_C" | "possible_value_D";
}

export class APIObjectB {
    // In this context, "Property1Value" refers to the version in APIObjectB
    public get property1(): APIObjectB.Property1Value {
        // ...
    }

    public get property2(): APIObjectB.Property2Value {
        // ...
    }
}

module APIObjectB {
    // Valid values in APIObjectB
    export type Property1Value = "possible_value_E" | "possible_value_F";
    export type Property2Value = "possible_value_G" | "possible_value_H";
}
```

Note that you will need to use the fully qualified name for the return types of your properties. For example, you need to use `APIObjectB.Property1Value` instead of just `Property1Value`.