# Can you create nested classes in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a way to nest classes in TypeScript. E.g. I'd like to use them like:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

Comment: For older typescript (<1.6), see [Any way to nest classes in typescript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13495107/any-way-to-nest-classes-in-typescript)

Answer (score 229, accepted):

In modern TypeScript we have class expressions which you can use to create a nested class. For example you can do the following :

```
class Foo {
    static Bar = class {
        
    }
}

// works!
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

Comment: this example doesn't work in Typescript 1.6.3:

Error TS4028 Public static property 'Bar' of exported class has or is using private name '(Anonymous class)'.

Comment: @Sergey I had the same problem so started using namespaces as per my answer below.

Comment: Is there a way to create interface inside a class? i.e. if we want that Bar will be an interface

Comment: @LittaHervi - One use case would be returning a private implementation of an external interface from, for example, a factory method. Another example from Java (and others) are iterators that require privileged access to member variables of their containing class and through scoping rules automatically do so, but you never want these to be exported and instantiated directly.

Comment: This allows you to construct a new instance yes but it can't be used as a type far as I can tell.

Comment: Any way to reuse the nested class from the parent class?

class Foo {
    static Bar = class {  };
    fieldA: Bar; //doesn't work: Cannot find name 'Bar'
    fieldB: Foo.Bar; //doesn't work: 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as namespace here.
}

// works!
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = new Foo.Bar();

Comment: This doesn't let you use the inner type in type annotations.

Comment: I just learned that you can't use property decorators with this syntax :(

Comment: I had to use `static Bar = class Bar {}` in order to have yet another class nested in it.

Answer (score 67):

Here is a more complex use case using ***class expressions***.

It allows the **inner class** to access the `private` members of the **outer class.**

```
class classX { 
    private y: number = 0; 

    public getY(): number { return this.y; }

    public utilities = new class {
        constructor(public superThis: classX) {
        }
        public testSetOuterPrivate(target: number) {
            this.superThis.y = target;
        }
    }(this);    
}

const x1: classX = new classX();
alert(x1.getY());

x1.utilities.testSetOuterPrivate(4);
alert(x1.getY());
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/brettnieland/pen/QMLGgj)

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh Is the ability to access private members inside an "inner" class expression a bug?

Comment: I verified this is correct usage with the TypeScript team.
 
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17535#issuecomment-319187970

Comment: is it possible it access parent context without passing this directly ?

Comment: @shabunc not to my knowledge

Comment: idea if you need a "true" (not "static") inner class (as an object template), then use it like `() => new class`

Comment: Is there a cyclic reference in the code above? Maybe use weak reference?

Answer (score 23):

I couldn't get this to work with exported classes without receiving a compile error, instead I used [namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html):

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    export class Foo { }
}

namespace MyNamespace.Foo {
    export class Bar { }
}
```

Comment: Same. 'Foo' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

Answer (score 17):

If you're in the context of a type declaration file, you can do this by mixing classes and namespaces:

```
// foo.d.ts
declare class Foo {
  constructor();
  fooMethod(): any;
}

declare namespace Foo {
  class Bar {
    constructor();
    barMethod(): any;
  }
}

// ...elsewhere
const foo = new Foo();
const bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 8):

#### Static nesting

Defining the static nested class `Foo.Bar` can be done in the following two ways.

1. **Option 1: Implementing `Bar` inside class `Foo`.**
   The type is declared in a `declare namespace` declaration.

   ```
   class Foo {
       static Bar = class { }
   }

   declare namespace Foo {
       type Bar = typeof Foo.Bar.prototype
   }

   let bar: Foo.Bar = new Foo.Bar()
   ```
2. **Option 2: Implementing `Bar` inside namespace `Foo`.**
   The type is automatically declared using declaration merging.

   ```
   class Foo { }

   namespace Foo {
       export class Bar { }
   }

   let bar: Foo.Bar = new Foo.Bar()
   ```

#### Non-static nesting

Defining the non-static nested class `Foo.prototype.Bar` may be done as follows.
The type is declared in a `declare namespace` declaration.

```
class Foo {
    Bar = class { }
}

declare namespace Foo.prototype {
    type Bar = typeof Foo.prototype.Bar.prototype
}

let foo: Foo = new Foo()
let bar: Foo.prototype.Bar = new foo.Bar()
```

> ***Note:**  the call `new Foo.prototype.Bar()` doesn't work, although it is valid Typescript even without type declaration.*

Answer (score 2):

I Hope this can be helpful

**Able to:**

- Create a new inner class instance
- Access outer class instance/prototype members
- Implement interfaces
- Use decorators

**Use Case**

```
export interface Constructor<T> {
    new(...args: any[]): T;
}

export interface Testable {
    test(): void;
}

export function LogClassName<T>() {
    return function (target: Constructor<T>) {
        console.log(target.name);
    }
}

class OuterClass {
    private _prop1: string;

    constructor(prop1: string) {
        this._prop1 = prop1;
    }

    private method1(): string {
        return 'private outer method 1';
    }

    public InnerClass = (
        () => {
            const $outer = this;

            @LogClassName()
            class InnerClass implements Testable {
                private readonly _$outer: typeof $outer;

                constructor(public innerProp1: string) {
                    this._$outer = $outer;
                }

                public test(): void {
                    console.log('test()');
                }

                public outerPrivateProp1(): string {
                    return this._$outer._prop1;
                }
                
                public outerPrivateMethod1(): string {
                    return this._$outer.method1();
                }
            }
            return InnerClass;
        }
    )();
}

const outer = new OuterClass('outer prop 1')
const inner = new outer.InnerClass('inner prop 1');

console.log(inner instanceof outer.InnerClass); // true 
console.log(inner.innerProp1); // inner prop 1
console.log(inner.outerPrivateProp1()); // outer prop 1
console.log(inner.outerPrivateMethod1()); // private outer method 1
```