# Access members of outer class in TypeScript

Tags: oop, typescript, closures, inner-classes

Since TypeScript 1.6, we can easily create inner classes with [class expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494174/can-you-create-nested-classes-in-typescript). In other OOP-centric languages like Java, inner classes can access members of the outer class, [even private ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801718/why-can-outer-java-classes-access-inner-class-private-members).

This behavior is similar to concept of closures, where function could access variables from the scope in which it was defined.

Why I can't achieve this in TypeScript? Does specification of classes in ECMAScript 2015 plays role here?

Code that presents expected behavior:

```
class OuterClass {
    private outerField = 1337;

    public InnerClass = class { 
        public accessOuter() {
            return this.outerField; // outerField not defined
        }
    }
}

var outer = new OuterClass();
var inner = new outer.InnerClass();
var win = inner.accessOuter();
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244695/279393 for another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easier to understand why you can't do that if you look at the compiled javascript of your code:

```
var OuterClass = (function () {
    function OuterClass() {
        this.outerField = 1337;
        this.InnerClass = (function () {
            function class_1() {
            }
            class_1.prototype.accessOuter = function () {
                return this.outerField; // outerField not defined
            };
            return class_1;
        }());
    }
    return OuterClass;
}());
```

As you can see, `outerField` is defined as a member of `OuterClass` like so:

```
this.outerField = 1337;
```

When you try to access it in your `InnerClass` you do:

```
return this.outerField;
```

But the `this` here is the instance of `class_1` and not `OuterClass` so there's no `outerField` in `this`.
Also, you have no access from the inner class to the instance of the outer class.

The way this is solved in java is like so:

```
class OuterClass {
    private int outerField = 1337;

    public class InnerClass {
        public int accessOuter() {
            return OuterClass.this.outerField;
        }
    }
}
```

But there's no equivalent to `OuterClass.this.outerField` in typescript/javascript.
Look at typescript inner classes more like static inner classes in java, but here too you'll only be able to access public properties:

```
class OuterClass {
    public static outerField = 1337; // has to be public

    public InnerClass = class { 
        public accessOuter() {
            return OuterClass.outerField;
        }
    }
}
```

You can pass an instance of the outer class to the inner class:

```
class OuterClass {
    public outerField = 1337;

    public InnerClass = class {
        constructor(private parent: OuterClass) {}

        public accessOuter() {
            return this.parent.outerField;
        }
    }
}
```

But again, you'll need to have `outerField` public.

---

#### Edit

In case you want to achieve something that will simulate the needed behavior (that is, the inner class instance will have access to a private outer class members), then you can do something like this:

```
interface OuterClassProxy {
    outerField: number;
}

interface IInnerClass {}

class OuterClass {
    private outerField = 1337;

    static InnerClass = class implements IInnerClass {
        constructor(private parent: OuterClassProxy) {}

        public accessOuter() {
            return this.parent.outerField;
        }
    }

    public createInnerClass(): IInnerClass {
        let outerClassInstance = this;

        return new OuterClass.InnerClass({
            get outerField(): number {
                return outerClassInstance.outerField;
            },
            set outerField(value: number) {
                outerClassInstance.outerField = value;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It's quite a lot of work, but it will do it.

Answer (score 10):

@Nitzan 's answer is great. I just wanted to add that I came up with this recently, maybe it helps:

```
class Outer {

    constructor() {
        this.val = 1337;
    }

    get Inner() {
        let Outer = this;
        return class {
            accessVal() { return Outer.val; }
        }
    }

}

new (new Outer()).Inner().accessVal(); // 1337
```

Comment: Probably a good idea to add an interface for the inner class where it's used

Answer (score 2):

Here is the correct way to do this in Typescript:

```js
class OuterClass {
  private outerField = 1337;

  get InnerClass() {
    const thatOuterField = this.outerField // <-- Notice this addition
    return   class {
      public accessOuter() {
        return thatOuterField; // outerField not defined
      }
    }
  }


}

let outer = new OuterClass();
let inner = new outer.InnerClass();
let win = inner.accessOuter();

alert(win); // test works!
```

No need for anything convoluted.

Comment: this is the same approach Kosmas already posted 6 months before

Comment: You wouldn't be able to modify outerField though...

Answer (score 0):

This one did not work so bad for me:

```
function use<T>(value: T) {return new class {with<U>(f: (value: T) => U) {return f(value)}}}

class OuterClass {
    private outerField = 1337;

    InnerClass = use(this).with(outerThis => class { 
        accessOuter() {
            return outerThis.outerField; // outerField not defined
        }
    }
}
const outer = new OuterClass()
const inner = new outer.InnerClass()
const win = inner.accessOuter()
console.log(win)
```