# Get the type of a nested class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm using *nested classes* in TypeScript by using the following code:

```js
class Parent {
  private secret = 'this is secret'
  
  static Child = class {
    public readSecret(parent: Parent) {
      return parent.secret
    }
  }
}
```

This is based on [the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32494175/1513045). It allows my `Child` class to access private properties of the `Parent` class.

I want to type a variable with the nested class type, I started naïvely with the following code:

```js
type NestedType = Parent.Child
const child: NestedType = new Parent.Child()
```

But I get the following error:

```
'Parent' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here. ts(2702)
```

I tried to use the `typeof` operator:

```js
type NestedType = typeof Parent.Child
const child: NestedType = new Parent.Child()
```

But it doesn't work:

```
Property 'prototype' is missing in type '(Anonymous class)' but required in type 'typeof (Anonymous class)'. ts(2741)
```

Finally I was able to make it work:

```js
const nestedTemplate = new Parent.Child()
type NestedType = typeof nestedTemplate
const child: NestedType = new Parent.Child()
```

However, this code creates a useless instance of `Child`. Is this a limitation of the TS language?

FYI, I also tried by using namespaces:

```js
class Parent {
  private secret = 'this is secret'
}

namespace Parent {
  export class Child {
    public readSecret(parent: Parent) {
      return parent.secret
    }
  }
}
```

But then the `Child` class is no longer able to access the private properties of the `Parent` class:

```
Property 'secret' is private and only accessible within class 'Parent'. ts(2341)
```

Comment: You could write `type NestedType = typeof (new Parent.Child())` to avoid the `nestedTemplate` constant and the instance creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `typeof` child prototype should be enough to resolve your typings trouble.

```js
class Parent {
  private secret = 'this is secret'

  static Child = class {
    public readSecret(parent: Parent) {
      return parent.secret
    }
  }
}

const child: typeof Parent.Child.prototype = new Parent.Child();
console.log(child.readSecret(new Parent()));
```

You can test it there [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDWgAcEBLANzDSWgiWGQwF5oByNACxJi5roZbx4CENJRLBoAYU4gAJtGahIMHPgJEArgCMQ46MjCyAynyRoAFIUSo0ALjjX0ASixD1BBhoQoijtADpaejM3AgBfNwjcKLxgAHsUEWhgGVl7NABPQiQ4gDMHZHR-aRI5f2I4tEqs6mYUJAB3Apti1PMnAG5YhIg4kCR-EDiAc3MU0tl-A2NTC3qm+EKLJxWOoA)

That way you do not have to instantiate any intermediary classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Child` class via the interface property access notation (`foo["bar"]`):

```
class Parent {
  private secret = 'this is secret'
  
  static Child = class {
    public readSecret(parent: Parent) {
      return parent.secret
    }
  }
}

type ParentChildProto = (typeof Parent)["Child"];

const child: InstanceType<ParentChildProto> = null!; // same as assigning to `new Parent.Child()`
child.readSecret(new Parent());
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcCmA7ALtA3gWAFDWgAcEBLANzDSWgiWGQwF5oByNACxJi5roZbwFBNNJRLBoAYU4gAJtGahIMHPgJEArgCMQ46MjCyAynyRoAFIUSo0ALjjX0ASizD1+sxoQoijtADpaejM3aABfYQjcKLw0AE9CanhkdGkSOVgEAHs0LIVoc3jErIAzBxS0JwBtACI0uRqAXQBuPDxgLJQIDGAZWXsASS7RFGAkABUEpAAeZJt62UycrIA+fJQNEBAAQmboAHp9mjAAW2pIaGUSAHMUEhRr6FzoAAMUJAB3cpt-BfMnF7tPr+AzGUwWd5fObof5OZpAA)

Edit: Use built-in `InstanceType` see comment.

Comment: `InstanceType` already exists and odes the same thing as your `InstanceOf`